# Button with same width does not have same width

Tags: html, css, styled-components

I am using `styled-components` in my `react` application.
Following is my styles

```
export const SignUpNowButton = styled.button`
  background-color: #1d4ea3;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #1d4ea3;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 16em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: "SofiaProSemiBold";
`;

export const AlreadyAMemberButton = styled.div`
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  color: #1d4ea3;
  border: 1px solid #1d4ea3;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 16em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "SofiaProSemiBold";
`;

<SignUpNowButton onClick={goToSignUp}>Sign up now</SignUpNowButton>
      <AlreadyAMemberButton onClick={goToLogin}>
        I am already a member
      </AlreadyAMemberButton>
```

Following is the screenshot of the buttons

[image]

I can't understand why they differ in widths as they have the same properties.

Comment: upload u r code in codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/) and share the link

Comment: Try with the same text length, do they still defer?

Comment: @СвободенРоб Yeah i tried with same text length and they still defer. This issue occurs only when I use styled-components. When using normal css it works fine

Comment: try "display:block" in your buttons, should work, because the rest is ok

Comment: @Trueman does not work

Comment: I am wondering about width:16em, can you test for example width:300px?

Comment: @Trueman same issue. I even tried percentage and rem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to give a brief explanation on **WHY** this is happening (with links providing a more complete explanation):
One of the components is a style.**button** and the other is a styled.**div**. So:

Button and div have **different default properties**.
`button` has a default `box-sizing`: **border**-box; in most modern browsers (each browser has its own defaults, thats why we use [normalize.css or reset.css](https://css-tricks.com/lodge/v10/011-normalizing-our-css-foundation/)).
`div` has a default `box-sizing`: **content**-box

- [The box-sizing property](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) tells the browser how to consider padding when calculating width/height.

So you have to normalize your style in some way.. choose your own adventure:

- Set both to be the same `box-sizing`.
- Set them both to be the same `styled` type. `style.button` or `style.div`, so they will inherit the same defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I think that something is inherited for specified elements. "**Sign up now**" is a `styled.button` and "**I am already a member**" `styled.div` - while only "**Sign up now**" has the proper width (`16em` with font size `17px` gives `272px` of width). The "**I am already a member**" button is wider, try to change it to `styled.button`, same as for "**Sign up now**"

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your page don't have CSS rule `box-sizing: border-box`.
Try

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```